# javascript delete JSON key in all array positions but maintain childrens

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following array of jsons:

```
var array_json = [{"my":{"id":144,"price":12500000}},
{"my":{"id":145,"price":13500000}},{"my":{"id":146,"price":13450000}},
{"my":{"id":147,"price":11500000}},{"my":{"id":148,"price":15560000}}]
```

I want to delete the "my" keys in every array's indexes but maintaining the rest of information. I mean, what i want:

```
array_json = [{"id":144,"price":12500000},{"id":145,"price":13500000},
{"id":146,"price":13450000},{"id":147,"price":11500000},
{"id":148,"price":15560000}]
```

How can this be done?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```js
var array_json = [{"my":{"id":144,"price":12500000}},
  {"my":{"id":145,"price":13500000}},{"my":{"id":146,"price":13450000}},
  {"my":{"id":147,"price":11500000}},{"my":{"id":148,"price":15560000}}];
    
array_json = array_json.map( function( value ) {
  return value.my;
});
    
console.log( array_json )
```

Comment: You should make note that this re-assigns `array_json` to a new array.

Comment: @rgthree yes, but OP can assign it to any other variable. `map` method creates new Array and not re-assigns original array. Also in OP example seems like he want it to be re-assigned.

Comment: I was merely suggesting you make note in the answer, not that the answer was incorrect :)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript

This will loop through your array and reassign the index with just the contents of the .my property.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array_json.length; i++) {
    array_json[i] = array_json[i].my;
}
```

Comment: Your code is wrong, it will work only for first object. http://jsfiddle.net/rb2y2wvc/ you should change `0` to `i`

Comment: Yeah that was a typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
    var array_json = [
        {"my":{"id":144,"price":12500000}},
        {"my":{"id":145,"price":13500000}},
        {"my":{"id":146,"price":13450000}},
        {"my":{"id":147,"price":11500000}},
        {"my":{"id":148,"price":15560000}}
    ];
    var objs= new Object(); 
   for (x in array_json) {
       objs[x]=array_json[x].my;
       alert(objs[x].id);
       alert(objs[x].price);
}
```

Now you have:

```
objs=[
      {"id":144,"price":12500000}},
      {"id":145,"price":13500000}},
      {"id":146,"price":13450000}},
      {"id":147,"price":11500000}},
      {"id":148,"price":15560000}}
]
```

you can check here: http://jsfiddle.net/igoralves1/xszqj0du/1/